# How can matlab be unable to find an anonymous function?

Tags: matlab

I get a strange error when running my script:

```
Unable to find function @(x) exp(x) within H:\blabla\myClass.m.
```

when I debug I get:

```
34  b=myAnonymousFunction(a)
K>> myAnonymousFunction(3)
Unable to find function @() exp(x) within HH:\blabla\myClass.m.
K>> class(myAnonymousFunction)
ans =
function_handle
```

A minimal example I was trying to produce worked fine.

Do You have any Idea where the error comes from and what it means?
Because he obviously can find the definition of insanity...ahh... myAnonymousFunction. Is it just a bug? I read [something on matlabcentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/92070) but its 7 Years old and doesn't give an explanation.

Further explanation:

I'm running MATLAB 2012 b under Windows 8 64 bit. The source files were originally written under a 64 bit Linux.

I don't think it's relevant but myAnonymousFunction is a parameter to a function in myClass and stored within a cell array. So it's like this:
file myClass.m:

```
classdef myclass < handle
  properties
    x=1337;
    myAnonymousFunctions;
  end
  methods
   function new = myClass(myAnonymousFunctions)
     new.myAnonymousFunction=myAnonymousFunction
   end
   function show(o)
     disp(myAnonymousFunction{1}(o.x));
   end
  end
end
```

and gets called like

```
myMyclass = myClass({@(x)exp(x)})
myMyClass.f();
```

Comment: What is `myAnnonymousFunction`? Is it the main class implemented in `myClass.m`? If so, why isn't the file also called "myAnnonymousFunction.m"? If not, can you explain a bit about the class/function hierarchy?

Comment: myAnnonymousFunction is a variable containing an anonymous function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible Workaround: **restart Matlab**.

After restarting MATLAB the Problem didn't occur ... so far.

I guess buggy ML debugger was buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error when using an anonymous function in a class.  The function was stored as a field inside a Matlab class as:

dataBlockObj.processStream(dataBlockObj.activeProcessStreamIndex).func=@(x) x;

and I had been debugging the code, however the error occurred while I was running the code on the command line without any breakpoints set.  The solution for me was also restarting Matlab.  I was running Matlab 2012b 64bit on a Windows 2008 Server.